# Group by multiple columns with different members of the same hierarchy?

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have customer data in a table structure like this:

```
customerID | productLine1 | productLine2 | productLine3
1          | 1            | null         | null
2          | 2            | 1            | null
3          | 4            | 2            | 1
```

Each customer is assigned to at least 1 product line but a maximum of three product lines.

I would now like to see how many customers I have for each product line.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Important: I do not wish to turn columns into rows (which would be a solution).
So the result would be:

```
productLine "1" --> 3 customers
productLine "2" --> 2 customers
productLine "4" --> 1 customer
```

Comment: But your sample output is rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ( replace `tbl` with your table name):

```
WITH Unpivoted
AS (
    SELECT customerID
        ,ProductLineSlot
        ,ProductLine
    FROM (
        SELECT customerID
            ,productLine1
            ,productLine2
            ,productLine3
        FROM tbl
        ) p
    unpivot(ProductLine FOR ProductLineSlot IN (
                productLine1
                ,productLine2
                ,productLine3
                )) AS unpvt
    )
SELECT ProductLine
    ,count(*) AS [Number Of Customers]
FROM Unpivoted
GROUP BY ProductLine;
```

Or you can rewrite that without CTEs or derived tables:

```
SELECT
    ProductLine,
    COUNT(*) AS [Number Of Customers]
FROM
    tbl AS t
    UNPIVOT
    (
      ProductLine
      FOR ProductLineSlot IN (productLine1, productLine2, productLine3)
    ) AS u
GROUP BY
    ProductLine
;
```

To elaborate a little on how the query works, the UNPIVOT clause turns your table into a row set like this:

```
customerID  ProductLineSlot  ProductLine
----------  ---------------  -----------
1           productLine1     1
2           productLine1     2
2           productLine2     1
3           productLine1     4
3           productLine2     2
3           productLine3     1
```

Rows where *ProductLine* is null are automatically omitted by UNPIVOT. You can see that the above row set can be grouped by *ProductLine* to get row counts per group for the final result:

```
ProductLine  Number Of Customers
-----------  -------------------
1            3
2            2
4            1
```

And that is what the query does.

Answer (score 0):

Because `COUNT` eliminates NULL values, you can use `COUNT` on each column:

```
SELECT COUNT([productLine1]) AS [productLine1]
     , COUNT([productLine2]) AS [productLine2]
     , COUNT([productLine3]) AS [productLine3]
FROM tbl
```

You will get a warning, [which is expected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10952/meaning-of-set-in-error-message-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-o/18454#18454). If you'd like to avoid that, you can use [`SUM` with a `CASE` statement in place of the `COUNT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216245).